# Scrollable dropddown not fully visible

Tags: html, css, scroll, dropdown, nav

I have a navbar with a scrollable dropdown item(cart view) to the right side of it.
The problem is that if there are more than one item in the cart, the top part of the dropdown it is not visible anymore.
Could you please tell me where is the problem?
This is the html:

```
 <body>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="App">
            <nav>
                <div class="links">
                    Something, something
                </div>
                <div class="asd">
                    bla
                </div>
                <div class="grand-parent">
                    <div class="bro">
                        bla
                    </div>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <div class="dropdown-content">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.App {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #1D1F22;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 9990;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-left: 70px;
    height: 80px;
}

.links {
    justify-self: flex-start;
    position: relative;
}
.asd {
    align-self: center;
    position: relative;
}

.grand-parent {
    right: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 90vh;
}

.bro {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 6px;
    margin-right: 170px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 90vh;
}

.dropdown-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 325px;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 1px solid black;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 90vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The project is done in ReactJS, but I think that this is not so important.
Thank you!

Comment: Before looking any further, did you notice you have a typo in `grand-parent`?

Comment: @Sven No, I did not notice that typo, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You centered vertically your elements in `.dropdown-content` with `justify-content: center;`
To fix it, you need to change it to `justify-content: flex-start;` and normally it'll works.

Comment: Thank you, very much. It worked. I was thinking that the problem might be the position of `.dropdown-content` and its parrents.  If it is possible could you please explain why your answer is the solution?

Comment: Because your dropdown-content has a max height and your content is bigger than the Max height. And you add a justify center, so instead of allowing scrolling you centered vertically your content